# Why does my input accept all values, even though I'm using a function to prevent this?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have this textbox on my website in which you can put a amount of euro's. So in this textbox it should only be possible to typ in numbers and comma's (no numbers).

CODE :

```
<script>
    $('#goed_doel_bedrag').keyup(function (e) {
        commaOnly($(this),'float');
    });
    function commaOnly(input,format){
        var value = input.val();
        var values = value.split("");
        var update = "";
        var transition = "";
        var expression=/(^\d+$)|(^\d+\.\d+$)|[,\.]/;
        var finalExpression=/^([1-9][0-9]*[,\.]?\d{0,3})$/;
        for(id in values){
            if (expression.test(values[id])==true && values[id]!=''){
                transition+=''+values[id].replace('.',',');
                if(finalExpression.test(transition)==true)
                {
                    update+=''+values[id].replace('.',',');
                }
            }
        }
        input.val(update);
    }
</script>
<div id="simplr-form">
    <br/>
    <? echo $goed_doel?>
    <br><br>
    Bedrag: <input type="text" step="any" min="0" name="goed_doel_bedrag" id="goed_doel_bedrag" placeholder="Vul hier het bedrag in">
    <br/>
```

Comment: `<input type="number">` --> no JS needed

Comment: If i do that, it won't accept comma's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing `$(document).ready(function(){});`

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#goed_doel_bedrag').keyup(function (e) {
    commaOnly($(this),'float');
    });
});
```

Comment: where should I put it?

Comment: Around:
$('#goed_doel_bedrag').keyup(function (e) {
        commaOnly($(this),'float');
    });